# Google reCaptcha widget cut off in Chrome

Tags: reactjs, recaptcha, react-google-recaptcha

I'm trying to add a reCaptcha validation using [react-google-recaptcha](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-recaptcha). Works fine but the widget is visually cut off in Chrome and I'm not sure how to fix it. Firefox renders the widget correctly.

I tried messing with the style (width, height, transform) and nothing worked.

Looks fine in Firefox:

[image: Looks fine in Firefox]

But it breaks in Chrome

[image: And this is how it looks in Chrome]

Code is here, there's nothing to it. Just using the most basic example. I tried both size options ('normal' and 'compact') and it didn't help either.

```html
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css';
import LogInForm from "./pages/user/LogInForm";
import Home from "./pages/home/Home";
import ReCAPTCHA from "react-google-recaptcha";


function App() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/login" element={<LogInForm/>}/>
                <Route path="/captcha" element={<ReCAPTCHA
                    sitekey="site key here"
                />}/>
                <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
            </Routes>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? Or maybe some workaround?

Comment: Posting some relevant code would be helpful for us to see where the problem is.

Comment: I added code, don't think it's going to help much though. It's just the most basic use of the component I can think of. I'm not sure what else to share to help solve the problem.

Comment: i have recpatcha v3 and works fine on chrome [https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3)

Comment: I have to use captcha v2

Answer (score 0):

Possibly caused by minimum font size in the browser settings. I had the same problem.

In my chrome it was set to 16. When decreasing to 12 my reCaptcha looks better.

I don't know if there is a workaround in code for this.